# Shape formatting & colour transparency in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to find the best way to create a shape in Access that is semi-transparent. I am not sure if this is possible but i would like to have a rectangle which is semi-transparent so i can use it to cover certain objects so the user can see the object but with an opaque visual type effect.  Is there some code that can help do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ms Access does not currently support transparency

Comment: It does answer '<i>I am not sure if this is possible</i>' and is providing the assistance the OP requested. If you disagree with my answer you should state why

Comment: @E Mett: ms-access does provide transparency. "Semi-transparency" is the thing which does not work.